# Preserving spaces when written to file

Tags: c++, text, io

I have a queue that's populated with the following:

```
'c', 'c', 'c', 's', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 's', 'c', 'c', 'n', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'e'
```

I'm trying to write to .txt file the following:

- if front of queue is 'c', find the number of successive 'c's, write that number to file
- if front of queue is 's', write a space to file
- if front of queue is 'n', write a newline to file
- if front of queue is 'e', stop

My algorithm is below:

```
void writeToFile(queue<char> &input) {
    int numC;
    ofstream myFile;
    myFile.open("file.txt");
    while (input.front() != 'e') {
        if (input.front() == 'c') {
            numC = 0;
            while (input.front() == 'c') {
                numC++;
                input.pop();
            }
            myFile << numC;
        } else if (input.front() == 's') {
            myFile << " ";
        } else if (input.front() == 'n') {
            myFile << "\n";
        }
        input.pop();
    }
    myFile.close();
}
```

`file.txt` should contain the below:

```
3 4 2
3
```

But it contains the below:

```
342
3
```

Why are spaces not put into the file? I'm using Linux if it matters.

Comment: oh, for a queue that doesn't have a "peek" function, just a "pop if not empty and return"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you check for 'c' in the inner loop, you pop 'c' off the queue until you reach 's', which subsequently fulfills the loop and the first if block, and proceeds to input.pop() at the end of the outer while loop, which moves you to the next character, so 's' is never checked against your if statement.

Comment: I see the problem now, thanks! If I `pop` inside each `if` block, it works as expected.